# does ui router not work in jade?

Tags: angular-ui-router, pug

I am setting up a simple crud app.  However, I am not sure what is going on with ui-router.  I read that you should use html tags so I tried this as well.  Here is my code.

app.js

```
app.get('/templates/:templateid',indexController.getTemplate);
```

index controller

```
var indexController = {
index: function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
},
getTemplate:function(res,req){
    res.render('templates/' + req.params.templateid);
}
```

};

module.exports = indexController;

Here is my main.js

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlProvider){
    $stateProvider('home',{
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl:'templates/home.jade',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
})

app.controller('HomeController',function($scope){

    console.log('home is here');
})
```

My index.jade shows as so

```
    extends layout

block content
    h1 Lets Get Cruddy

    <div ui-view></div>
```

I have called ng-app in my layout.  This should be fairly simple right?

Answer (score 0):

The router only interprets html

you should point the template url to the compiled html file so

```
templateUrl:'templates/home.html
```

that's if `templates/home.jade` compiles to `templates/home.html`

Answer (score 0):

As Dr Manhattan said, AngularJS does not render a Jade file, however, if you have a server side language such as NodeJS, you can change view engine to Jade.

For simplicity sake, I would also recommend creating a NodeJS application with Express so you can create a route that will render the view and take advantage of the simplicity of Jade.

Add the following to your App.js file in your NodeJS application:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

In your NodeJS route, you will add something like this:
    var router = express.Router();

```
// index.js
// http://www.yourdomain.com/ is the path to this route
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'Express'
    });
});
```

In your main.js file, you will change the templateURL to the following:

```
templateUrl:'/',
```

Jade will render the template to HTML and make it readable for AngularJS.